# Mocha: testing event receiver

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js

I have been trying to test this code with no luck.

The logic:
This code will connect two clients -Client1 and Client2-, then Client1 will send a message to Client2 - thru a server. When the Server receives the message from Client1, it (the server) will respond to Client1 with an acknowledge message, and then, it will send the new message thru the 'newMessage' event.

The test:
Each client always listens to 'newMessage' event. In this test I want:
a. Connect Client1 and Client2 to server 
b. Send a message from Client1 to Client2 
c. When Client2 receives the 'newMessage' event, check the incoming data

I dont know if this is possible, all my approaches failed, but in fact, the application works.

```
describe('> Test case:\n', function () {

describe('> Connect Client1 & Client2', function () {
    this.timeout(2000);

    // Instantiate testing clients
    var client1 = new virtualClient(),
        client2 = new virtualClient();

    beforeEach(function (done) {

      // Connect the test clients
      Promise.all([client1.connect( users[0] ), client2.connect( users[1] )]).then(function () {

        // When both clients are connected, set a callback function to handle 'newMessage' event on Client2 (I wonder where to test this...)
        client2.client.setNewMessageCallback(function(data) {

          console.log("-----> Client2 received 'onNewMessage' broadcast");

          // Can I use a it() here? 

        });

        done();

      }).catch(function (error) {

          console.log(error);
      });

    });


    describe('Client1 sends a message to room with Client2', function () {


        // I now send a message from Client1 to Client2: this will make
        // the server fire the 'newMessage' event and Client2 should
        // receive it

        it('- Client1 sends a message to Client2', function (done) {

          client1.client.sendMessage(client2.data.user._id)
            .then(function (response) {

              // Should return an Object with properties 'roomId' and 'localRoomId'
              response.should.be.an.instanceOf( Object );
              done();
            });

        });

    });
});
```

});